# Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView#1e9ad27'

Tags: java, spring-mvc, content-negotiation

In rest-servlet.xml the below configuration is made ..

```
<property name="defaultViews">        
    <list>         
        <!-- JSON View -->          
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">        
        </bean>  

        <!--  XML view -->            
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">            
            <constructor-arg>                
                <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller">                   
                </bean>            
            </constructor-arg>          
        </bean>          

        <!--  PDF view -->          
        <bean class="com.hmkcode.view.PDFView">             
        </bean>

        <!--  XLSX "Excel" view -->          
        <bean class="com.hmkcode.view.ExcelView">             
        </bean>
    </list>      
</property>
```

---

The below error occurs.. can any one provide solution for this.
Thanks in advance

> SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver#0'
>   defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/rest-servlet.xml]: Cannot
>   create inner bean
>   'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView#1e9ad27' of
>   type [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView] while
>   setting bean property 'defaultViews' with key [1]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView#1e9ad27'
>   defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/rest-servlet.xml]: Cannot
>   create inner bean
>   'org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller#10651e1' of type
>   [org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller] while setting
>   constructor argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller#10651e1' defined in
>   ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/rest-servlet.xml]: Invocation of
>   init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/castor/core/util/AbstractProperties   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:290)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you miss the `castor-core.jar` in your classpath. Please add it.

if you use maven you can add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.castor</groupId>
    <artifactId>castor-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

to your pom.xml rebuild your project and deploy it again.